# Show f is continuous on (0, ∞) iff f is continuous at 1 for a defined function.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

**exercise:** Suppose that $f:(0,∞) → R$  satisfies $f(x) - f(y) = f(x/y)$  for all $x,y$ in $(0, ∞)$ and $f(1) = 0$.

Prove f is continuous on $(0, ∞)$ if and only if f is continuous at $1$.

(proof→:) Suppose that $f:(0,∞) → R$ satisfies $f(x) - f(y) = f(x/y)$ for all $x,y$ in $(0, ∞)$ and $f(1) = 0$.
Suppose f is continuous on (0,∞), then by definition f is said to be continuous at a point $a$ if for every $ε > 0$  there is a $δ > 0$ such that $|x-a| < δ$ implies $|f(x) - f(a)| < ε$.

Then suppose f is continuous at $1$, then by our defined function  f(x) - f(y) = f(x/y) , we get $|x-1| < δ$ implies $|f(x) - f(1)| = |f(x) - 0| = |f(x)| =  < ε$.

(proof ←) :Suppose that $f$ is continuous at $1$, then we need to show $f$ is continuous on every point $a$ on $(0, ∞)$. Thus, by definition, f is said to be continuous at a point $a$ if for every $ε > 0$ there is a $δ > 0$ such that $|x-a| < δ$ implies $|f(x) - f(a)| < ε$.
Thus, $|x-a| < δ → |f(x) - f(a)| = |f(x/a)| < ε$. Then $f$ is continuous on on $(0, ∞)$.

Please can anyone please help me verify this makes sense. If not, can someone please give any feedback/hints. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is correct, you could want to explain a few more words on the last inequality $|f(x/a)|<\epsilon$ if someone gets really picky.

Answer (score 2):

$(\Rightarrow)$: There is nothing to do!

$(\Leftarrow)$: Let $a>0$ and $\epsilon>0$. Suppose that $f$ is continuous at 1. We have to find $\delta>0$  such that:

> if $|x-a|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$

Since $f$ is continuous at 1, then there is $\delta_1>0$ such that:

> if $|x-1|<\delta_1$ then $|f(x)-f(1)|<\epsilon$

Take $\delta=a\cdot\delta_1>0$, then if $|x-a|<a\cdot \delta_1$ we have $|\frac{x}{a}-1|<\delta_1$ then (since $f$ is continuous at 1) we have $|f(\frac{x}{a})-f(1)|=|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$. And we are done!

Comment: GOOD JOB!!!!!!!!!!